# Recovering software raid after a hardware raid array was created on the disks

Tags: raid, hard-drive, software-raid, hardware-raid, disaster-recovery

I had a server with 4 x 500GB SSDs in a software RAID10 array. I moved these drives to a new machine that had an HP P410i Hardware RAID controller. I didn't want to use the hardware raid controller, as we use software raid, so I was going to just configure it as JBOD. When I booted up the RAID controller configuration in the new machine, I saw that it had already (automatically, without any confirmation) created a RAID5 array with all 4 of my disks. Scared of data loss, I removed the 4 drives and put them back in the old machine, and now it won't boot. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can get this working again?

Thanks!

Comment: You should post some details about the setup. If you use a *sysrescuecd* to boot, dump some info with `fdisk -lu`, `mdadm --examine`, or whatever you can find. Hopefully mdadm can still find some metadata on the drives. Then, depending on where the superblocks were (which version), you may be able to restore.

Comment: Recreate the RAID array and then restore from backup.